# Sending data with HttpClient post to Django backend

Tags: django, angular, post

I have been trying to send data from my Angular front end to my Django backend and the data doesn't seem to be sending and I can't figure out why. This is my code on the frontend...

```
const post_data = {
  email: form.value.email,
  password: form.value.password
}
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
});
const params = new HttpParams()
const options = {
  headers,
  params,
};

this.httpClient.post('https://my_website/signin/check/', post_data, options).subscribe(
  result => { console.log(result); },
  error => { },
  () => {}
)
```

and in my Django backend, I print the request.POST to see if the data is sent correctly, and nothing shows up. This is the result:

```
<QueryDict: {}>
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by it doesnt sent? Is there an error? Or is it a status code of 200 (success), but your backend does not receive a request body?

Comment: it simply doesn't receive it in the request body

Comment: But you don't seem to be checking the post body, you're showing a querydict which would only be populated by a form-encoded post. Please show the Django view code.

Comment: The only thing inside the view is a print statement 'print(request.POST)' - as said above

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(request.body)` in your view?

Comment: you can also try to see the result by printing `request.data`.

Comment: Looks like the data shows up in the request.body. How do I make it show up in the request.POST?

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned in the comments, request.POST would contain the data only if the data is populated by a form-encoded post. You can verify it by using POSTMAN to send a request with form-encoded data.

However, in your case using ***request.body*** will output the ***post_data*** that you have passed in the http request.